# jQuery - stop after lauching function once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stop launching my function after it's done one time. I have something like this:

```
function scrollBottom() {
    var biglink = $('div.nav a:last').attr('href');
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()) {
                $('div.nav').before('<div class="lazy"></div>');

                $('div.lazy:last').load(biglink + ' div.cnt > * ', function() {
                    $(this).css('background','0');
                    biglink = $(this).children('div.nav').children('a:contains("starsze")').attr('href');
                });
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is - each time I reach the bottom, I have a new `lazy` div created. I want to create just one, stop and them, after I finish the loading (`load` callback) I want to relaunch it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

before creating a new `lazy` div check if one is present already or not

```
if(!($(".lazy").length>0)){
 //create new one
```

Comment: I thought of that, but the problem is, when one `lazy` is created, I want, after user scrolls even lower (reads loaded content), to create another `lazy` div and load more. Problem is - I'm getting something like multiple `lazy` divs when user scrolls while content is being loaded.